# Angular - accessing class properties within `compareWith` function

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I am trying to implement custom compareWith function, that I am using on `<select [compareWith]="compareWithFn">`. However I've found out, that I can not access class properties within this function. Example:

```
export class FormRowSelect {
  @Input() optionKey = 'id';

  compareWithFn(object1: object, object2: object): boolean {
    return object1 && object2 ? object1[this.optionKey] === object2[this.optionKey] : object1 === object2;
  }
}
```

This function does not work, because when I try to console.log the `optionKey`, it returns undefined. When I replace the `object[this.optionKey]` with `object['id']`, suddenly it starts working. Do you have any ideas how to make this work?
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!:)

Answer (score 2):

You can define `compareWithFn` as [an instance arrow function](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/%27this%27-in-TypeScript#use-instance-functions) to preserve `this` context:

```
compareWithFn = (object1: object, object2: object): boolean => {
             ^^^                                           ^^^^
            note this                                       and this
  ...
}
```

Alternatively you could use [Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) method to bind context in constructor:

```
export class FormRowSelect {
  @Input() optionKey = 'id';

  constructor() {
    this.compareWithFn = this.compareWithFn.bind(this)
  }
  
  compareWithFn(object1: object, object2: object): boolean {
    ...
  }
}
```